# how to trust certificate based on CA, not on thumbprint bases in android application

Tags: android, azure, ssl-certificate, ca

I have followed the instruction mentioned on link  https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#UnknownCa to connect to an HTTPS server with self-signed certificate.
I have uploaded certificate to the azure service and added same cert in android app then it was working fine, but when i have changed the certificate from same CA in service, it stop working. It is giving an error **javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found**

But according to the Google article app should trust all the certificates from same CA.

I also checked on this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826045/Android-security-Implementation-of-Self-signed-SSL (please refer DRAWBACK section of this page) , acc. to this page  it is not possible to communicate with different certificate in service and application.

Please let me know can I trust the certificates in android application based on CA ?

Answer (score 0):

Why trying to use self signed cert when you can get trusted SSL cert for free from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). And then you dont have to deal with such things.

Comment: you are correct, but i want to do it with self signed cert.